# Using database transactions in ASP.NET MVC3 with Ninject DI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, data-access-layer

I'm starting a new project and want to do things better than I've done before. I used Windsor for DI but it didn't go great. I've been eyeing up using the NuGet Ninject MVC 3 package to take care of DI.

I've Googled around for many hours and found lots of helpful advice about Ninject (especially liking the filters DI stuff) but nothing that really answers the following burning scenario...

Scenario:

- I have a SQL Server database for persistence. I want all access to the database to be in a transaction.
- I'll be using repositories to access domain objects that are stored in the database.
- A controller might need to use multiple repositories to do it's work and hence the data access needs to be the same instance based to each repository to avoid locking issues.
- The data access should be per request made to web app.

My confusion/pondering:

- If Ninject shoves in an appropriate DB factory or context to all my repositories then where (and how) would I put code to commit on successful completion or rollback if an exception occurs? Ideally you wouldn't want to do this for every controller action so I'm guessing in the global asax EndRequest event but how to know whether to commit or rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Sharp Architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)'s implementation of this - although they use Windsor, the same approach can be used with Ninject.

Basically you add `Transaction` attributes where required on Controller methods - the plumbing is all handled by the Sharp Arch framework.

Comment: From reading several of the pages from Sharp Architecture it sounds like I'd have to install a whole bunch of 3rd party libraries, use NHibernate and use Sharp Architecture just to use the Transaction attribute - that seems like a massive amount of overkill since about the only 3rd party library it mentions I'm likely to use thus far is NUnit.

Comment: Agreed - it was not my intention to suggest this approach to you - merely to demonstrate an architectural practice in action, that works. Obviously you'd need to write your own implementation of said attribute.

Comment: Doh! Of course, lol; Got the source and it does seem like it should be fairly simple.